# Swift: Access own property from superclass

Tags: swift, class, inheritance

I have a superclass with this property:

```
private(set) public var elementsStored = 0
```

Now I have a subclass that makes the superclass threadsafe and overrides the property like this:

```
override public var elementsStored: Int {
    get {
        print("Getting sub-class-property.")
        self.lock.lock()
        defer { self.lock.unlock() }
        return super.elementsStored
    }
    set (newValue) {
        print("Setting sub-class-property.")
        self.lock.lock()
        defer { self.lock.unlock() }
        super.elementsStored = newValue
    }
}
```

When I call `self.elementsStored` in the **superclass**, the **subclass**-property gets fetched.

How can my superclass access it's **own** property?

To clarify my problem: My subclass calls a superclass method using `super.add(element)`. The superclass-method accesses `self.elementsStored`. However instead of reading it's own (the superclass') `self.elementsStored` it reads the property of the subclass. But I want to access the original property not the overridden one.

Comment: Doesn't `elementsStored` or `self.elementsStored` work? I'm not quite sure what you mean by that last question. Can you give an example?

Comment: No, whenever I use `self.elementsStored`, the line "Getting sub-class-property." is printed; so it's accessing the subclass' one.

Comment: Ok, so you want to access a property of the superclass inside an instance of the subclass?

Comment: I edited my question. English is not my mother tongue so it's a bit hard sometimes to explain my problems; sorry 

Comment: The whole point of overriding a property or method like this is so when you access it through a reference to the superclass, you'll get the overridden subclass behavior. Dynamic polymorphism depends on this behavior. There are not two versions of the property in there, so expecting the subclass to "read its own" property is just a mistake in thinking. If you don't want the subclass to be able to override a property, you'll need to make it `final` in the superclass, otherwise you are asking for the behavior that you are seeing. You probably need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a private variable in your base class to use as storage for your inheritable property. Any other way would break polymorphism.

```
public class baseClass {
     private var internalElementsStored = 0

     private(set) public var elementsStored : Int {
         get {
             return internalElementsStored
         }

         set {
             internalElementsStored = newValue
         }
     }
}
```